# How do I make the Object Inspector show more TColor property values?

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe, propertyeditor

The IDE Object Inspector shows TColor properties with a drop-down ColorBox,  and the color can be selected by name - clBlack etc, as defined in the Graphics unit. The problem is that the clWeb colors also defined in the Graphics unit are not present, and any custom colors I define are also not there.

So how do I extend the defined colors that are selectable in the Object Inspector?

PS Delphi XE

Comment: Are the colors shown for the `Color` property of *other* controls, besides the one you wrote? Is this a question about your custom component, or about how to add new colors in general?

Comment: The same color list is present on, say , a TColorBox dropped onto a VCL form. Custom defined colors are present in the code completion window in the editor, but are not present in the Object Inspector.

Comment: I see. Since your question isn't related to your custom component, I've removed that part of your question. Also, the Code Completion window is showing you the `clWeb` colors because it's really showing you *all* integer constants — you've just already typed `cl` before you looked at the list. `TColor` is just an integer; there's nothing inherently special about those constants. It's the built-in `TColor` property editor that knows to display those specific values.

Comment: I will revert to this issue when I get a chance to investigate further. My development machine (a laptop) died a sudden and horrible death, and I am still setting up a new machine..

Answer (score 1):

I would try to derive a class from TColorProperty (unit VCLEditors) and override GetValue/GetValues/SetValue. See [here](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=93199) for a detailed discussion.

**Edit:** My original link is broken by now. Try the thread [Custom colors in Delphi 7](https://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.vcl.components.writing.general/browse_thread/thread/40ea919d2d92d484/885b7b40e19b6012#885b7b40e19b6012) (in borland.public.delphi.vcl.components.writing.general) instead.

Comment: Ah, that does look promising. Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt - That link is now broken.  Goes to an Embarcadero page that says "The specified message [93199] was not found."